# default webview is not working

Tags: android, android-webview

Hi i'm working with listview onclick load webview this works fine.

my issue is now before onclick listview i use a default web page to load in the webview
this is not working...

Here is my code

```
webview=(WebView)app.findViewById(R.id.webView);
webview.loadUrl("http://google.com");//this is my default webview before onclick the list view
```

the above default url is not loading...

```
ListView listView = (ListView) menu.findViewById(R.id.list);
initListView(listView);
public  void initListView(final ListView listView) {
    // By using setAdpater method in listview we an add string array in list.
    ArrayList<ItemDetails> image_details = GetSearchResults();
    listView.setAdapter(new ItemListBaseAdapter(this, image_details));

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { 
            Object o = listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            ItemDetails obj_itemDetails = (ItemDetails)o;
            String msg =obj_itemDetails.getName();
              try{
            if(null!=webview){
                webview.removeAllViews();
              }
            if(msg.equalsIgnoreCase("a")){
                 webview.loadUrl("http://example.com");
            }else if(msg.equalsIgnoreCase("b")){
                 webview.loadUrl("http://example.com");
            }else if(msg.equalsIgnoreCase("c")){
                 webview.loadUrl("http://example.com");
            }else if(msg.equalsIgnoreCase("d")){
                 webview.loadUrl("http://e.com");
            }else if(msg.equalsIgnoreCase("e")){
                 webview.loadUrl("http://f.com");
            }else{
                 webview.loadUrl("http://example.com");
            }


          }catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(HorzScrollWithListMenu.this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);

            }

        }  
    });

}
```

MY onCreate code section

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    scrollView = (MyHorizontalScrollView)   inflater.inflate(R.layout.horz_scroll_with_list_menu, null);
    setContentView(scrollView);

    menu = inflater.inflate(R.layout.horz_scroll_menu, null);
    app = inflater.inflate(R.layout.horz_scroll_app, null);
    webview=(WebView)app.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webview.loadUrl("http://google.com");
```

Please let me know what goes wrong in my code.?

Comment: Did you add INTERNET permition in Manifest?

Comment: ya i have added.. onItemClick its works... only issue is before that i have added default webview that is not working

Comment: From this webview=(WebView)app.findViewById(R.id.webView); I assume you are not loading the webview inside the onCreate() method. Where do you load webview?

Comment: Okay what the app. stands for? Do you need it?

Comment: could you remove the if(null!=webview){webview.removeAllViews();} just for testing

Comment: View app = inflater.inflate(R.layout.horz_scroll_app, null); // is the layout view

Comment: Okay I got it. @XepterX, he said it works on click, so I guess that wont be a problem.

Comment: i remove the if(null!=webview){webview.removeAllViews();}  still the issue remins

Comment: @Sathish, thats what I was trying to tell him.

Comment: Could you post the onCreate() method if it is not too long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help you

```
webView = (WebView) app.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com")
```

also don't forget to add this permission in you manifest file,

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Or go with **WebViewClient**.

```
web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");


 public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
     @Override
     public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
     }

     @Override
     public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      view.loadUrl(url);
      return true;

     }

     @Override
     public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onPageFinished(view, url);

      progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     }
    }
```

Comment: @Sathish: where you can use this, inside an adapter of activity

Answer (score 0):

Try setting these properties on the webView

```
webview.clearCache(true);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

And try follwing this tutorial for proper basic understanding of the Web View working
[Here](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2011/11/basic-webview.html)

Comment: @Satish : Could you elaborate more please (Problem) , Do you have a ListView and a WebView layouts in your activity ?

Comment: onItemclick i will display the different url on the same webview is is my concept...this works fine... my issue is before onitemclick i have set one webview as the default webview.. that webview is not working.....